# Is there some way I can avail google domain authentication in my webapp made with ExpressJS

Tags: express

I am working on a project that's a portal for students and alumni from my university. This will feature a login form and signup that should ideally authenticate with the domain email id provided by the University.

Comment: Have you not found any tutorial?

Comment: None that's relevant to my case. Would appreciate if someone can let me know where to look